# Latitude and Daylight Hours

Tags: earth-rotation, seasons, sun, astronomy

*What is the relationship between the latitude and daylight hours for each season?*

When I interpret the answer for the question, I believe the number of daylight hours decreases as the latitude increases as fall goes to winter. Then, when winter goes to spring, and spring goes to summer, the daylight hours increase as the earth rotates. Though, my answer is vague, in my opinion.

Comment: This looks like homework, so I'll give a hint rather than an answer. What dates mark the start of each season? What happens on those dates?

Comment: Check out [this animation](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/lu9tp6/hours_of_daylight_around_the_world_as_the_year/) regarding the question on Reddit.

Answer (score 2):

This [tool](http://astro.unl.edu/classaction/animations/coordsmotion/daylighthoursexplorer.html) lets you determine daylight hours from latitude for any day of the year.

I feel like this answer should be longer, but there is not much more to say.

Comment: That is an *very nice* tool! Very simple interface and yet so much can be shown.